# How to define axis names in WCS

Tags: astropy, libwcs

I'm trying to use WCS for simple linear, non-celestial axes. These are actually just the U,V coordinates representing the Fourier transform of an image.

```
import astropy.wcs as wcs
w=wcs.WCS(naxis=2)
w.wcs.axis_types[0]=0
w.wcs.axis_types[1]=0
w.wcs.ctype[0]='UU---SIN'
w.wcs.ctype[1]='VV---SIN'
print(w)
ww=w.deepcopy()
```

As I read the [documentation for axis_types](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.wcs.Wcsprm.html#astropy.wcs.Wcsprm.axis_types), I have specified that the first two axes are are linear axes (i.e. non-celestial). However when the deep copy executes, I get an error:

```
astropy.wcs._wcs.InconsistentAxisTypesError: ERROR 4 in wcs_types() at line 2486 of file cextern/wcslib/C/wcs.c:
Unrecognized celestial type (UU---SIN in CTYPE1).
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see that axis_types is an attribute and cannot be set in this way. It's apparent when trying to do: `w.wcs.axis_types=[0,0]` . Still not sure how to do this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `UU---SIN` and `VV---SIN`, just use `UU` and `VV`.   `wcs` is recognizing that the `SIN` projection indicates a celestial coordinate system, but `UU` and `VV` do not describe any celestial coordinate system.

```
import astropy.wcs as wcs
w=wcs.WCS(naxis=2)
w.wcs.ctype[0]='UU'
w.wcs.ctype[1] = 'VV'
w.deepcopy()
```

This raises a question, though, of whether there is a well-defined convention for (presumably gridded?) UV data in FITS images.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I don't know of an official extension for FITS images that are transforms. I believe using UU-- and VV-- plus the projection comes from AIPS from a long time ago. The -SIN is appropriate since u,v,w are defined relative to a given SIN projection. For this reason, the RA and DEC axes are sometimes retained as celestial coordinate system. Someone should sort this out one day but it's not me! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe AIPS still does this and I am disappointed that WCSLIB objects.
UU---SIN etc seems a right way to describe what we have in such gridded
images.  Actually FFT does use this axis type while UVIMG simply uses U
and V.